# Require parameter on devise sign-in every time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a checkbox (like a terms of use) that I need to be checked every time a user signs in.

I've seen some examples on adding a checkbox on the sign up page, adding a virtual attribute to the User model, etc.

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :username, 'Username'
    = f.text_field :username
  %p
    = f.label :password
    = f.password_field :password
  %p
    %span
      = check_box_tag :terms_of_use
      I have read the
      = link_to 'Terms of Use', '#'
  %p
    = f.submit 'Sign in'
```

Here's my devise route:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions' }
```

And here's the custom controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    if params[:terms_of_use]
      super
    else
      # Not sure what to put here? Is this even the right track?
      # Also, redirect the user back to the sign in page and let
      # them know they must agree to the terms of use.
    end
  end
end
```

**How would I go about requiring the checkbox to be selected every time a user signs in?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post may help: http://hollandaiseparty.com/order-of-abstractcontrollercallbacks/

Adding a prepend_before_action should allow you to check for the terms_of_use and redirect if needed before allowing Devise to take over. Something like:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  prepend_before_action :check_terms_of_use, only: [:create]

  def check_terms_of_use
    unless params[:terms_of_use]
      # Since it's before the session creation, root_path will take you back to login
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```